# ESRI fc is called database.DBO.fcname and version is called SDE.fcname

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase

ArcSDE 9.3.1 and MS SQL 2008 R2
In ArcCatalog the feature class is called database.DBO.fcname and when I look at the connection properties in ArcCatalog the default is called DBO.Default and the other versions are called SDE.versionname1 and SDE.versionname2.  We just migrated to MS SQL 2008.  I did not do the install of sde on the new server.  The databases were not created new on the new server instead they were backed up and then restored to the new server from a MS SQL 2000 db and then upgraded to 2008 databases.  Is the sde on SDE.versionname1 referring to the schema or the owner?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version names follow a owner.name convention so the SDE user owns the version named versionname1 and versionname2. Also, versions are a view of the entire database, not just a single feature class. There is not a 1:1 relationship between feature classes and versions. The ArcGIS help has additional info:  [Understanding Versioning](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Understanding_versioning)